# I want to get object from anchor tage using jquery but something is wrong in my code

Tags: jquery, pug

I have following jade and js. Js is not grabbing the data-user which is sent as object

**jade**

```
ul.user-account
  li
    a(href='#', data-user='[{"name":"ABC", "image-path":"images/123.jpg"}]')
      img(src='images/123.jpg')
      span.account-name ABC
  li
    a(href='www.abc.com')
      img(src='images/64.jpg', data-user='[{"name":"HYTG" , "image-path":"/images/64.jpg"}]')
      span.account-name HYTG
```

**js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.account-name', function (e) {
    $this = $(this);
    var userinfo = $this.data("user");
    console.log('userinfo' + JSON.stringify(userinfo));  //says undefined
    return false;
});
```

Comment: You're already storing JSON string in `data-user`, why calling `JSON.stringify()` again?

Comment: Also, you're missing the closing bracket in the first `li.data-user`.

Comment: userinfo is undefined, how do i grab it ?

Comment: `userinfo` is undefined or `JSON.stringify(userinfo)`?

Comment: either way is the same thing

Comment: @haim770 .data() parses json string to object automatically

Comment: @Anton, why use `JSON.stringify` then?

Comment: @haim770 because then the log would be userinfo[object Object] or userinfoundefined in OPs case since the selector was wrong

Comment: @Anton, Now that you fixed your original comment i understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're registering a click event on the `span` tag, not the `a` tag that contains the data. You have to call `.data()` on the parent `a` tag.

Replacing the following should do the trick.

`$this = $(this);`

with

`$this = $(this).parent();`